# How text align text filter in ffmpeg with multi line text

Tags: ffmpeg

how text align center, right , left positions with drawtext with multi line as input.

"Hello \n
world"

Comment: But positions are relative to input but not relative to the textbox which we are creating. I need alignment of text i.e center, left, right. Not the position of text in the video. How that can be possible?

Comment: By default , I am getting left align by default.

Comment: I am using Method 3: Line break in command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## drawtext

I can think of two methods for text alignment in drawtext:

1. Use a monospace font and add the required number of spaces in line 2.
2. Use 2 drawtext instances to independently position each line.

Neither method is ideal.

## subtitles

Using ASS subtitles could be a better solution.

- The [*Alignment* parameter](http://docs.aegisub.org/3.2/ASS_Tags/#%5Can) (or `\an` tag) controls the general text alignment and placement.
- The optional [`\pos` override tag](http://docs.aegisub.org/3.2/ASS_Tags/#%5Cpos) allows more precise placement.

The behavior of `\pos` changes depending on the Alignment. See the [`\pos` tag](http://docs.aegisub.org/3.2/ASS_Tags/#%5Cpos) documentation for examples.

Once you create the ASS file, such as with [Aegisub](http://www.aegisub.org/), you can add the subtitles with `ffmpeg`.

#### Softsubs

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -i subs.ass -map 0 -map 1 -c copy output.mkv
```

#### Hardsubs

Using the [subtitles filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf "subtitles=subs.ass" -c:a copy output.mkv
```

Comment: Got it , But  how to load  external font file in .ass file for font

Comment: @KonduriSaiAditya That's a new question. Different topic. Should be a new and separate post. This answer is directly addressing "How text align text filter in ffmpeg with multi line text". Stack Overflow is intended to be 1 question per post.

Answer (score 2):

FFMPEG doesn't seem to support Alignment in the drawtext command, we need to manually do so.
i had the same issue,
but to solve that i took a different approach,
you can follow the same steps.

1. After adding your text, when you want to save it..
2. Convert those texts into the image
3. Add those images to FFMPEG with the help of the "Image overlay command".

i hope these steps help.

Comment: I had done the same Vaidehee. Thank you for the answer.